# Traefik http redirect to https using docker label

Tags: docker, traefik

I am using traefik as docker service in swarm mode.
Traefik accept some labels to configure how it will handle docker containers and create the proxy for it.

I can define a label `traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https` in docker service to override Traefik `defaultEntryPoints`, but users will need to make request using `https`. I want to expose entry points, `http` and `https`, but if the user make a request using `http`, Traefik redirects it to `https`.

Is it possible to use `entryPoints.http.redirect` as docker label to force redirect for some specific services? I don't want to set it in `traefik.toml` file, because it will be applied to all service, I want it to just some services, not all of them.

Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a bit of a struggle with the selected question (which is correct) so here is some more pieces of information.

If you followed the [official Let'Encrypt tutorial](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/docker-and-lets-encrypt/) from Traefik docs, you end up with this piece of configuration:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
```

In the `entryPoints.http` there is the `entryPoints.http.redirect` rule that tells Traefik to implement the redirect to https.

If you to cherry-pick the services that should implement the redirects, you first need to disable this global behaviur:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
```

and at this point, you can apply the label to the services that you want to redirect:

```
labels:
  ...
  - "traefik.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https"
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As a result of [this merge](https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/2133) introduced into [traefik version 1.5](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/configuration/backends/docker/), it is now possible to do:

```
labels:
- "traefik.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https"
```

Answer (score -1):

Still an open issue -> not possible right now.

https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/541